# Visual Studio Code sidebar selection color

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

How to change visual studio sidebar file highlight/selection color?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `list`.

Go to `User Settings`, add these lines:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.hoverBackground": "#535353",
    "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#fff",
    "list.activeSelectionForeground": "#000",
    ...      
  }
```

There are many configuration for `list`, for example `"list.hoverBackground": "#535353"` set highlight color while your hover on it, `"list.activeSelectionBackground": "#fff"` set highlight color after you select/click one file, `"list.activeSelectionForeground": "#000"` set font color of the selected item right after you select/click it.
You should explore the rest of them and don't forget to read the description for each configuration, type `ctrl+space` on each configuration to read the description.