# Is it possible to change the selection background colour in VSCode Sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is the screenshot from the **Sidebar** in VSCode:

[image]

It's not easy to see (at least for my eyes) that SearchBar.js is selected.
Is there any way that I could change the background colour for the selected file to make it more recognisable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code sidebar selection color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813427/visual-studio-code-sidebar-selection-color)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943631/vscode-change-highlight-color-of-current-file/52956233#52956233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`settings.json`

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.focusBackground": "#61afef60",
    "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#008cff50",
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#008cff50",
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot @Alex